# Qt: how to save QTextEdit contents with custom properties

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I have a text editor (QTextEdit). Some words in my editor contains additional information attached (namely, two corresponding integer positions in wave file for that word). 
They are stored in Python object as custom properties for QTextCharFormat objects (I attach them with code like this: `self.editor.textCursor().setCharFormat(QTextCharFormat().setProperty(MyPropertyID, myWordAttachment)` )

Unfortunately, if I save my document to html, all of that additional formatting is lost.

So, I want to perform simplest task: to save my document with all of it's formatting,including myWordAttachment (and to load it from disk).

Am I right that Qt5 doesn't have something ready for it, and I have to write all that document's serialization code by myself? (I still hope that where is simple function that did the job)

Comment: that I know you must save those properties manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.you loop your text every character.

2.and you catch the character and its charFormat()

3.and you get the properties.

4.Because the properties are eventually a value of something, `int`,`str`,...
  So you get the properties by `charFormat().property(1),(2),(3)`... or `properties()`

5.The most important thing is the character's position & the range.You get the position during the 1th loop.

6.When you catch the CharFormats, you insert into something hashable object like list.
  & and you don't forget to insert the CharFormats position.

6.you save your document and the position & properties.

My suggestion for your solution.

1.you can get `characterCount()` by the `QTextDocument` object.

2.you loop the range of the `characterCount()`

3.Before doing it, you make a `QTextCursor` object.

4.you set the textcursor at the first position.(movePosition method & `Start` moveoperation & KeepAnchor flag)

5.you move the cursor to right one character & Another.

6.you check the character's charFormat() by `tc.charFormat()` and the `tc.position()`

7.But it is the time to Think twice. CharFormat is always the bunch of characters.
  you probably get some characters of the same CharFormat().
  You can  prepare for it.I can Think about some way,but... you should set the QCharFormat objectType or propertyId() for specifing the `QCharFormat` in Advance(during editing your document).Why don't you set the texts into the properties for after saving & loading.I hope you manage to pass here during debugging & tring.

8.if you get a charFormat,and you check the objectType().

9.if the objectType() is the same as Before searched, you pass the search engine without doing anything.

10.The second important thing is that calls `clearSelection()` each searching.

11.You save your document() as it is html strings.and you save the charFormats() properties.

12.when you load your document(),the html sentence comes back.
   and load the properties.

13. you make QTextCursor and setPosition( the property's position saved in advance.)
14. you move QTextCursor until the position and you select the target texts.
15. you adopt the charFormat properties again and the end.

Summary
 The important thing how you specify the charFormat().
 You can catch the charFormat without any problem.but the charFormat() is adopted in some range.So you must distinguish the range.

1.The targeted texts is set in the QTextCharFormat's property.
2.You have The QTextCursor pass during the same QTextCharFormat's object.

I can Think of them...

I Think it is some helps for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I end up with solution like yours (but mine was less universal). It's a pitty that developers don't think about this simple task, so we have to invent the wheels here.